# Как из Delphi IdHttpServer ответить на GET запрос, что бы поддерживалась кроссдоменность?

Tags: javascript, html, delphi, cross-domain

На GET запрос клиента отвечаю так:

```
  AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
  AResponseInfo.CustomHeaders.Add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := текст html страницы;
  AResponseInfo.WriteContent;
```

Html подгружает *GamePlatform.js* так

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="platform/js/GamePlatform.jsv=1400771587"></script>
```

который подгружает *config.xml* так

```
function loadConfig()
{
    this.$error.hide();

    // TODO: config.xml should be removed and all settings for the game platform should
    // be taken from PlatformSettings.xml
    Loader.cacheTimestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    var configXMLLoader = new XMLLoader("config.xml");
    configXMLLoader.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.COMPLETE, onConfigXMLLoaded, this);
    configXMLLoader.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.ERROR, onConfigXMLError, this);
    configXMLLoader.load();
}
```

Вот ошибка:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://213.27.32.135:8080/games/mobile/config.xml?v=1499689563754. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://213.27.32.135' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Файлы находятся в Apache Tomcat. Как мне сделать что бы они подгружались?

Comment: почему то мне кажется, что вы не на этот `http://213.27.32.135:8080/games/mobile/config.xml?v=1499689563754` запрос отвечаете, как указано в коде ( с добавлением `access-control` заголовка) а на другой, видимо какой-то основной.  Ибо пишите, что выдаете html. Ибо я так понял вы отдаете html (где пишите заголовок), а уже потом эта страница запрашивает асинхронно xml-файл. Тут вам и выдается ошибка, что заголовка нет для хмл

Comment: @teran ну да, все как вы и сказали, я с своего сервера 213.27.32.135 отвечаю на запрос с access-control, а потом эта страничка делает другой запрос, уже в tomcat 213.27.32.135:8080, на файл GamePlatform.js, а он третий запрос в tomcat 213.27.32.135:8080 на файл config.xml

Comment: ну дак ваши заголовки относятся только к начальному запросу, как вы и сказали "делает _другой_ запрос", по этой цепочке же они не передаются. Кто отдает непосредственно этот xml, тот и заголовок должен выставлять, т.е. tomcat

Comment: tomcat отдает, то есть мне нужно что бы он ответил с таким заголовком? Понимаю что тема другая,  но это возможно?

Comment: "да" по всем пунктам. Но как - не знаю, с томкатом и видимо джавой не знаком :)